# SQL Alchemy Core query to pandas dataframe, when pandas.read_sql takes so long that it is useless

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, sqlalchemy

I'm having a simple problem: pandas.read_sql takes far, far too long to be of any real use. To read 2.8 million rows, it needs close to 10 **minutes**. The query in question is a very simple SQLAlchemy object that translates to "SELECT * FROM [TABLE]" in raw SQL.

On the other hand, that same query finishes in a few seconds using SQLAlchemy's execute.

So, clearly, I need to use the latter. The problem is, I still need to load the information into a dataframe, which is what I assume to be the source of the problem.

What is the most efficient way to load the result of execute(select_object) into a pandas dataframe?

I tried to use the library conectorx but it does not support a SQLAlchemy select object. While the example I provided is extremely simple, in reality I need to dynamically assemble complex queries according to user input, so I cant simply write all of my SQL manually.

All the solutions I found simply say "use pandas.read_sql" using trivial examples with no regards to reasonable execution times.

Comment: Have you tried / is it possible to bypass SQLAlchemy and just pass in your raw select to pandas?  Have you tried setting a `chunksize` for `read_sql()` to get rows in batches rather than individually?

Comment: I am currently seeing if I can organize the code in a way that takes advantage of chunk processing. However, because the results of one query are immediately fed to the next, it is proving difficult.

Comment: I think a more appropriate comparison than _pandas.read_sql_ vs. _execute(select_object)_ would be _pandas.read_sql_ vs. _execute(select_object).all()_.

Comment: Reading 2.8 million rows into a pandas dataframe could be slow for all kinds of reason - one of them being not enough memory so lots of paging happening. Have you calculated the memory requirements of a row (multiplied by 2.8 million)? What are you doing when you say sqlalchemy runs in a few seconds - doing what? Does that include retrieving the data and putting it into some object in in memory?